# Monte Carlo Tree Search for card games like Belot and Bridge, and so on

Tags: artificial-intelligence, montecarlo

I've been trying to apply MCTS in card games. Basically, I need a formula or modify the UCB formula, so it is best when selecting which node to proceed.

The problem is, the card games are no win/loss games, they have score distribution in each node, like 158:102 for example. We have 2 teams, so basically it is 2-player game. The games I'm testing are constant sum games (number of tricks, or some score from the taken tricks and so on).

Let's say the maximum sum of teamA and teamB score is 260 at each leaf. Then I search the best move from the root, and the first I try gives me average 250 after 10 tries. I have 3 more possible moves, that had never been tested. Because 250 is too close to the maximum score, the regret factor to test another move is very high, but, what should be mathematically proven to be the optimal formula that gives you which move to chose when you have:

- Xm - average score for move m
- Nm - number of tries for move m
- MAX - maximum score that can be made
- MIN - minimum score that can be made

Obviously the more you try the same move, the more you want to try the other moves, but the more close you are to the maximum score, the less you want to try others. What is the best math way to choose a move based ot these factors Xm, Nm, MAX, MIN?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem obviously is an *exploration problem*, and the problem is that with Upper Confidence Bound (UCB), the exploration cannot be tuned directly. This can be solved by adding an exploration constant.

---

The **Upper Confidence Bound** (UCB) is calculated as follows:

[image: Eq. UCB1]

with *V* being the value function (expected score) which you are trying to optimize, *s* the state you are in (the cards in the hands), and *a* the action (putting a card for example). And *n(s)* is the number of times a state *s* has been used in the Monte Carlo simulations, and *n(s,a)* the same for the combination of *s* and action *a*.

The left part (*V(s,a)*) is used to exploit knowledge of the previously obtained scores, and the right part is the adds a value to increase exploration. However there is not way to increase/decrease this exploration value, and this is done in the **Upper Confidence Bounds for Trees** (UCT):

[image: Eq. UCT]

Here *C<sub>p</sub> > 0* is the exploration constant, which can be used to *tune* the exploration. It was shown that:

[image: Eq. Cp]

holds the [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) if the rewards (scores) are between 0 and 1 (in [0,1]).

[Silver & Veness](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Silver/web/Publications_files/pomcp.pdf) propose: *C<sub>p = R<sub>hi</sub> - R<sub>lo</sub></sub>*, with *R<sub>hi</sub>* being the highest value returned using *C<sub>p</sub>=0*, and *Rlo* the lowest value during the roll outs (i.e. when you randomly choose actions when no value function is calculated yet).

---

Reference:

[Cameron Browne, Edward J. Powley, Daniel Whitehouse, Simon M. Lucas, Peter I. Cowling, Philipp Rohlfshagen, Stephen Tavener, Diego Perez, Spyridon Samothrakis and Simon Colton.
A Survey of Monte Carlo Tree Search Methods.
IEEE Trans. Comp. Intell. AI Games, 4(1):1–43, 2012.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6145622)

[Silver, D., & Veness, J. (2010). Monte-Carlo planning in large POMDPs. Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems, 1–9.](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Silver/web/Publications_files/pomcp.pdf)

Comment: Sounds nice. What if V(s,a) is in [0,260]? What is the optimal constant Cp in this case?

Comment: When I take a move, and playout it several times, I have values X1, X2, ..., XN - that are the scores at the leaf node (endgame) of each simulation. The problem is we don't know what is the distribution of these numbers, I can calculate the standart deviation, let's say: 2,4,4,4,5,5,7, and 9 are the values. In this case the average is 5, but the variance is 4, and the stardart deviation is 2. Another example I tried a move 4 times, and I have scores: 20, 30, 25 and 235. Obviously 235 is not likely to happen, so I want to use 25 in the formula, not the average score 77. Is this correct logic?

Comment: I updated the question on what value to use for Cp, and you could try to play a bit with the number (increase to explore more). I'm not quite sure what you want with the scores at the leaves. If you want to evaluate the policy you should do simulations with it, after having learnt it.